# How to iterate over pandas dataframe and check for the day in datetimeindex

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataframe with this datetimeindex:

```
...   Date                 A       B

190   2019-09-13 21:50:00  1       2
191   2019-09-13 21:55:00  3       2
192   2019-09-13 22:00:00  1       2
193   2019-09-13 22:05:00  3       2
194   2019-09-13 22:10:00  1       2
195   2019-09-16 06:00:00  1       2
196   2019-09-16 06:05:00  1       2
197   2019-09-16 06:10:00  4       2
198   2019-09-16 06:15:00  1       2
199   2019-09-16 06:20:00  4       2
200   2019-09-16 06:25:00  1       2

.....
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Now I need to count if A is larger or equal to B, but only the first time on each day.
How can I achieve it that the list is getting filled only with the first hit per day?

```
count = []

for i in df.index:
    if A[i] >= B[i]:
       count.append('A is larger than B' + f" on {df.Date[i]}")
```

My desired output according to this example would be

```
A is larger than B on 2019-09-13 21:55:00  
A is larger than B on 2019-09-16 06:10:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first filter rows by [`Series.ge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ge.html) (greater or equal, `>=`) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and then get first values by [`Series.dt.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.date.html) and [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
m = df['A'].ge(df['B'])

df1 = df[m].groupby(df['Date'].dt.date).first()
print (df1)
                          Date  A  B
Date                                
2019-09-13 2019-09-13 21:55:00  3  2
2019-09-16 2019-09-16 06:10:00  4  2
```

Or create helper column by dates and then use [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['d'] = df['Date'].dt.date

m = df['A'].ge(df['B'])

df1 = df[m].drop_duplicates('d')
print (df1)
                   Date  A  B           d
191 2019-09-13 21:55:00  3  2  2019-09-13
197 2019-09-16 06:10:00  4  2  2019-09-16
```

---

```
for d in df1.Date:
    print ('A is larger than B' + f" on {d}")
A is larger than B on 2019-09-13 21:55:00
A is larger than B on 2019-09-16 06:10:00
```

Comment: what is this doing `m = df['A'].ge(df['B'])`? In my original code I need to check if A is bigger or equal to B

Comment: @MarkT - yop, it is same - greater or equal - `ge`

Comment: It seems to work but I have trouble to implement this in my code because there I have an if condition which filters a certain time span, like 06:00 to 08:00. My fault, I should have mention this in my question.

Comment: @MarkT - So need [`DataFrame.between_time`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html) ?

Comment: I'll try it. Thank you. In my original code column A is sometimes already larger than B at the beginning of the day. This gives me wrong results because I only want to know if A gets bigger than B if it's smaller initially. Do you have a solution how to modify `m = df['A'].ge(df['B'])`accordingly ?